# SQL - show fields of table1 if condition works in table2

Tags: java, sql, tapestry

I do not know if this could be done exactly in SQL but I´m trying it with no luck at all so I would appreciate some help.

I have two tables: "Room" and "Booking". "Room" shows the hotel rooms and "Booking" are the reservations. Example:

From left to right, TABLE1, TABLE2 AND MY DESIRED RESULT

[image]

For example, I want to list the rooms available between two dates, this case, between 20 and 21.
Room 1 is not available (two dates booked), Room 2 not available (20 is booked) so it should list something like:

Some help? I tried some `LEFT JOIN`, blabla and not getting the correct result. For dates NOT IN (date1, date2) does not work for me because it should not be booked between date1 and date2.

I would appreciate your help so much.
Thanks

Comment: *FYI:* `Date` is a bad column name, since it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's the `outer join` / `null` approach:

```
select t1.roomid, t1.door
from table1 t1 
    left join table2 t2 on t1.roomid = t2.roomid 
         and t2.date >= '2016-08-20' and t2.date <= '2016-08-21'
where t2.bookingid is null
```

The key is moving the `where` criteria to the `on` portion of the `join`.

---

Here's another similar option using `not exists`:

```
select roomid, door
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from table2 t2
    where t1.roomid = t2.roomid and 
          t2.date >= '2016-08-20' and 
          t2.date <= '2016-08-21'
    )
```

Comment: thanks sgeddes! I´m goona try it right now to see if it works.

Comment: really fast answer...I´ll try it in 5-10 minutes and let you know if it works. I was trying with NOT EXISTS today and it did not work for me...

Comment: Option 3: Similar to option 2, but using `not in`. And all of them can be written using `between`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Sgeddes! It works, both solutions. I´m trying to understand it because solution1 was 90% similar to mine...

Comment: Sgeddes, could you explain the last line in Solution 1?
"where t2.bookingid is null"

My SQL sentence was identical minus the last line.

Comment: @eloygperez -- that's what removes the records from the `outer table`.  using an `outer join` with a `null` check is a common approach to your problem.  `exists` and `not in` can also work the same.  Here's a good article on joins (one area discussing just this): https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @sgeddes thanks again. I´m goona read that article and more about multitable sentences because I´m a bit lost...